# Не устанавливаются библиотеки на Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

Я совсем новичок.
На данный момент мне нужен `sympy` для расчета интегралов. Пишу в `IDLE` под виндой.
Exe-файл на втором же шаге сообщает, что не видит установленного питона. Пробовала другие поставить - то же самое. Что делать? Подозреваю, что проблема решается как-то очень просто, но опыта для нахождения этого решения нет.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А почему версия 3.2? Вообще для расчетно-научных задач удобно сразу поставить боле-мене новую Анаконду,  там и `sympy` "из коробки", и много всего другого полезного...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте поставить питон <=2.7.2.  Инсталлятор sympy собран с distutils именно 2.7.2. Либо из архива ручками, уверяю это не сложно. У меня на 2.6.Х установщик увидел без проблем.

Comment: да. версия 3.2. она не поддерживается?

Comment: Похоже что поддерживается "python 2.4 or newer". Я думаю проблема с исталятором. Пробуйте из сорцов: http://code.google.com/p/sympy/downloads/detail?name=sympy-0.7.1.tar.gz&can=3&q=

Распаковываете, потом выполняете в директории: python setup.py install

Если Вам не критична 2 или 3 ветка, советую поставить 2.Х.Х - в дальнейшем будет мньше проблем.

Comment: да. черех setup.py сработало. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка настройка системных переменных. *Попробуйте нажать <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> , запустить там `cmd` и написать в консоли `python.exe`.*

В случае, если `python.exe` не найден, то необходимо поправить системную переменную `PATH` в <kbd>Панель управления -> Система -> Переменные среды</kbd>.

Comment: вначале в cmd не запускалась - поправила. теперь запускается, но exe с sympy всё равно его не видит, та же ошибка.

Comment: @illaniel Если вы исправляли это, добавляя `python` в `PATH`, то может потребоваться перезагрузка.